# Custom Personalization Rules Available in Sitecore 10.1 XM

Tags: personalization

According https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/101/sitecore-experience-platform/the-personalization-conditions.html, there are many personalization rules that are still available in Sitecore XM.

My question is simply - can you still create custom Personalization rules in Sitecore XM, provided the custom rules do not read any Analytics/Xdb data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To start with custom personalization, you need to perform the below steps:

**Step 1:** Go to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Tags` right-click on Tags and add new customize Tag (I have given name CustomPersonalization):

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Conditional Renderings` and expand conditional rendering and add created tag into the Tags property of default tag as below:

[image]

**Step 3:** Go to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements`

- Right-click on Elements and add new Element folder (I have given the name
  CustomPersonalization).
- Right-click on CustomPersonalization and add new condition and set
  the Text and Type property of condition.

  *Text Property:* Give the condition with Rule which will show to the content editor.

  *Type Property:* Specify our class name with a namespace followed by the
  assembly name, where we will write our personalization rule business
  logic.

[image]

**Step 4:** Now you need to add created tag into default tag, Tags property of element folder:

[image]

**Step 5:** Write your personalization rule business logic as below or update your code as per requirement:

```
public class PersonaliseRuleService<T> : StringOperatorCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(ruleContext, "ruleContext");
            HttpCookie customCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Custom_Personalization"];      
        if (Value.ToLower().Equals(customCookie.Value.ToLower()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Step 6:** After completion of all the above changes, you need to set your personalization rule on the component using experience editor. Go to the page presentation details and select that rendering and click on personalize section. Add your personalization rule and select Edit rule then select our created rule and update the data source from the content property.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Same you can create a more custom rule to show relevant content to the visitor.
For more details blog post:

1. [Work with Custom Facet in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/06/work-with-custom-facet-in-sitecore-9.html)
2. [Custom Personalization Rules in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2019/05/customize-personalization-rules-in-sitecore-9.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is absolutely possible. Make sure you have `Xdb.Enabled` set to `false` to have xDB off but `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` to `true` so the rules work, below sample patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>     
      <setting name="Xdb.Enabled" >
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
      </setting>
      <setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="true" />
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```